# Docker postgres on local machine: connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I have a basic spring-boot application that does CRUD operations on a a postgres instance that is running on docker on my local machine. I am using Intellij to run my spring-boot application. When I run from the IDE, the application works fine with no errors.

But when I build a docker image out of the .jar file of my spring-boot app, I get the below error when I try to do a docker run.

Googled for a day before I posted the question here, help in any direction would help me!

**Docker file contents**

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

COPY  target/demo-*.jar /demo.jar

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/demo.jar"]
```

**Error stack trace**

```
Error Code : 0
Message    : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:60) ~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:80) ~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:438) ~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:149) ~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar!/:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar!/:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar!/:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:459) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar!/:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar!/:42.2.11]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56) ~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar!/:na]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:81) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar!/:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:93) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar!/:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:197) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar!/:42.2.11]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

Comment: If that's your docker file, how did PostgreSQL get into that Docker image? Are you sure your PostgreSQL database isn't in a different image? If it is, then the database is not on `localhost`, now is it?

Comment: Yes my postgres instance is in a different image. I am exposing the port 5432 on my posgtres docker image. Both the jar and the postgres instance are running on the same docker. The IDE is on the same machine as well

Comment: But they are different *containers*, so they are like different hosts or VMs, which means you need to name the container, not use `localhost`.